# How to use JsonObject in Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json

I am using JsonSerializer and not Newtonsoft for serializing and deserializing.
But with JsonSerializer I see that some of my chars like `&&` is changing to `\u0026` and `"` is changing to `\u0022`.

So, I was thinking to use `NewtonSoft`. But not sure how can I use it without `JsonObject`.

My code with JsonSerializer is :

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

JsonObject? content;
try
{
    content = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(stringContent);
}
catch (JsonException e)
{
    _// log it
}


if (content.ContainsKey("Test"))
{
    continue;
}

content.Add("Test", "blah blah");
string newContent = JsonSerializer.Serialize(content, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
});
```

Now with NewtonSoft, I dont know how to use JsonObject, as I want to use **containsKey and add**.

Comment: @gunr2171 I do not have c# model and I am scanning many json files, so I don't know if objects can be parsed to c#. I just want to see if a key is there and if not, just add that key and then serialize it and convert it back to string and store it

Comment: `JsonObject` is part of `System.Text.Json`, as shown by your `using` statements at the top of the file. You're not using Newtonsoft at all in that example.

Comment: JsonConvert.Serialize("&&");

Answer (score 0):

[`JsonObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonobject?view=net-6.0) is a class used in another Json serializer, you want to use [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm).

```
// parsing
JObject content = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(stringContent);

// checking if a property by key exists
bool propExists = content.ContainsKey("Test");

// adding a property
content.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty("Test", "blah blah"));

// rendering it back to a string
string output = content.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: For output should I do `content.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);` or `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content, Formatting.Indented);` ?

Comment: And I am just doing `content.Add(("Test", "blah blah"));` should be ok right ? Do I need JProperty ?

Comment: I'd personally recommend `ToString` over `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` when dealing with JObject/JArray, but it [produces the same output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WUI4X6). `content.Add(("Test", "blah blah"));` isn't valid.